# Does SSL alone prevent SQL injection?

Tags: ssl, sql-injection

I'm working on tightening up the security on my app and the first thing I'm planning on doing is serving the entire app via SSL. I'm wondering how secure this is if it were to be the only measure I take to secure the app.

For instance, let's say I have the following front-end code:

```
<input id="password" value="my_password_value" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#password').blur(function(){
            location.href = 'my_backend_script.php?password=' + $('#password').val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then in my backend script I have:

```
$user_ID = 1;
$password = $_GET['password'];
$USER_edit = mysql_query("UPDATE USERS SET password='$password' WHERE id='$user_ID'");
```

If the above example were running under an SSL connection, would it be safe from any SQL injection attacks?

**NOTE:**
I realize that prepared statements are the standard for preventing injection attacks, and that best-practice would be implemented, but I'm just curious as to how secure SSL is as a standalone solution.

**QUICK ANSWER:**
No, SSL does *nothing* to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

SSL does only secure the transmission channel between the client and server. But the client can still send malicious data over that secure channel.

Answer (score 4):

No, not really.  SQL Injection has nothing to do with the security of the connection, rather it has to do with the security of how you handle user input.  Using prepared statements helps prevent purposefully mis-formed input data from corrupting your SQL queries.

If all of your users are trusted users who must log in, using SSL can provide some level of security against SQL injection, as you would be more confident that the users who get into your application would not be attempting to hack your system.

But SSL is no substitute for properly writing your database access code.

Comment: It’s rather “No, not at all”. :)

Comment: Thanks @JeffOlson, that's exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: @JeffOlson : "If all of your users are trusted users who must log in, using SSL can provide **some level of security** against SQL injection, as you would be more confident that the users who get into your application would not be attempting to hack your system.": If I trust my logged in users and use SSL, why does this achieve only **some level of security** against SQL injection ? I think you have some cases in mind which I dont get. If yes, It would help to make them more explicit. Thanks.

Comment: There's always cross site scripting as a possible attack vector.  Or some other type of malware installed on the user's system that sends in malicious requests.  Or perhaps the user's account has been breached by a hacker stealing their password.   Those are a few I can think of...

Comment: @JeffOlson It's been years since I asked this question, and I've rescinded my acceptance of your answer. Given how many other people have visited this question, I think maybe it's time for refresh?

Comment: I don't think my answer will change, even though it's been over 5 years.

Answer (score 3):

The question that comes to my mind when I read this is: Where is the injection happening from ?

Is it a Man-in-the-middle who is injecting the rogue SQL or is it a logged-in user ? 
Using SSL will ensure (to a decent extent) that a MITM cannot sneak rogue data (including SQL) into my packets.

So, why are so many saying SQL injection is totally unrelated to SSL ? 
In my humble opinion, using SSL addresses many attacks to a decent extent.

For example, consider an existing application in which it is not feasible to apply one of the real solutions for SQL Injection : say, Prepared statements, owing to the amount of code churn that it will result in.

What can you do to easily achieve a better security for your app ? 
As @JeffOlson mentioned, if your users are required to login and once logged-in you trust them, then SSL is a sufficient solution (for SQL injection and a few other attacks).

Though you seem to already agree that SSL doesnt address SQL injection **fully** for **every** application.

Comment: Excellent point @brainOverflow. Now that I'm gaining a better understanding of how injection attacks happen I'm starting to see that the relationship between the two is closer than many would believe. I still think the best (quickest) answer is that SSL does nothing to prevent SQL attacks, but I'm also starting to see that both SSL and prepared statements should be used together in order to fully secure my app.

Answer (score 2):

SSL does not protect against SQL injection attacks at all. Prepared statements, views, etc are the solutions to SQL injection.